# OAuth Authentication - Check if user has already authorized Instagram App

Tags: php, oauth, instagram

So the first time someone uses my site they log in with Instagram, they're asked if they want to allow my app access and they click yes. Next time they come to my site they won't need to re-authorize my app because they've already done it.

What I want to know is how can I detect if they have already authorized it or not?

Comment: Post your code effort